# ReactSelect: pass in extra data to be used by custom render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-select

I am using React-Select.

Currently I am fetching data from elasticsearch and setting it to state:

```
var new_titles = []
body.hits.hits.forEach(function(obj){  // looping through elasticsearch
    new_titles.push({value: obj._source.title_id, label: obj._source.title_name})
})
this.setState({titleResults: new_titles})
```

Later I am using `this.state.titleResults` and passing it into my React-Select component:

```
<Select autofocus optionComponent={DropdownOptions} options={this.state.titleResults} simpleValue clearable={this.state.clearable} name="selected-state"  value={this.state.selectedTitleValue} onChange={this.handleTitleChosen} searchable={this.state.searchable} />
```

This works fine. But now I would like to pass in extra meta data pertaining to this title when users search my React-Select componentOptions. Something like this:
[image]

I am only passing in `{value: obj._source.title_id, label: obj._source.title_name}`, but I would like to pass in more information to be used by my `DropdownOption` component:

```
const DropdownOptions = React.createClass({
    propTypes: {
        children: React.PropTypes.node,
        className: React.PropTypes.string,
        isDisabled: React.PropTypes.bool,
        isFocused: React.PropTypes.bool,
        isSelected: React.PropTypes.bool,
        onFocus: React.PropTypes.func,
        onSelect: React.PropTypes.func,
        option: React.PropTypes.object.isRequired,
    },
    handleMouseDown (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopPropagation();
        this.props.onSelect(this.props.option, event);
    },
    handleMouseEnter (event) {
        this.props.onFocus(this.props.option, event);
    },
    handleMouseMove (event) {
        if (this.props.isFocused) return;
        this.props.onFocus(this.props.option, event);
    },
    render () {
        return (
            <div className={this.props.className}
                onMouseDown={this.handleMouseDown}
                onMouseEnter={this.handleMouseEnter}
                onMouseMove={this.handleMouseMove}
                title={this.props.option.title}>
                <span>Testing Text</span>
                {this.props.children}
            </div>
        );
    }
});
```

How would you pass in more information into this component?

Comment: where are you calling `DropdownOptions`? Can you post that code. Your question is how to render more content in the `DropdownOptions` component?

Comment: @realseanp `DropdownOptions` is being passed into `<Select ... />`. That is the code. It is a module called React-Select: https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select . My question is how to pass in more data to `DropdownOptions` component instead of just having the title render. As shown in my example, I would like year, episode, etc to be available for each dropdown option.

Comment: I need an example for customOption in react select. Please any one could help me?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well if I am looking at the code correctly it looks like you can pass in an optionRenderer prop along with your optionComponent.

https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select/blob/master/src/Select.js#L874

It takes your option as an argument so hypothetically you can pass additional fields in your option object and render via the optionRenderer function. Maybe something like this...

```
// ...
optionRenderer(option) {
    return (
        <div>
            {option.value} - {option.label} - {option.someOtherValue}
        </div>
    )
}
// ...
render() {
    let selectProps = {
        optionComponent: DropdownOptions,
        optionRenderer: this.optionRenderer,
        options: this.state.titleResults,
        simpleValue: true,
        clearable: this.state.clearable,
        name: 'selected-state',
        value: this.state.selectedTitleValue,
        onChange: this.handleTitleChosen,
        searchable: this.state.searchable,
        autofocus: true
    }
    return <Select {...selectProps} />
}
```

Comment: By `<Select {... selectProps} />` do you pass in select props just as a keyword? Like... `<Select {selectProps} />`? 

Also, should I then not alter my `DropdownOptions` at all?

Comment: Yeah it doesn't look like you need to edit `DropdownOptions` and the `{...selectProps}` is adding the entire object as props. It is the spread operator, https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/jsx-spread.html. Just makes for better readability.

Comment: This is now replaced with "Components". https://react-select.com/components