# How can I add custom props to an Option using React Select?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-select

My goal is to add a tooltip when the user expands the  menu and hovers over the items listed. To do this, I need to add `data-tip` and `data-for` to the menu items.

The `options` I'm passing to React Select looks like this:

```
  [
    { value: 1, label: 'Onw' },
    { value: 2, label: 'Two' },]
```

I'd like to just add the prop info there but I don't think there's a way. Do I need to customize the rendering of each option? Any tips on how to do this would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Hi there! Amybe duplicate from this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38383720/reactselect-pass-in-extra-data-to-be-used-by-custom-render

Comment: @Tico that looks likie just what I need, thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ReactSelect: pass in extra data to be used by custom render](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38383720/reactselect-pass-in-extra-data-to-be-used-by-custom-render)

Answer (score 3):

You can simply wrap your custom `Option` inside a function then assign custom props for it

```
components={{ Option: (optionProps) => <Option {...optionProps} onEditItem={onEditItem}
    onDeleteItem={onDeleteItem} />  }}
```

[image]

Comment: is there a way to achieve this without having to use the custom 'Option' component?

Comment: Hi @nymphadora,

It was long time, the I don't know what is the current behavior of it. But based on the code on the screenshot, I guess it's only accept the component, so We have to pass the component

Answer (score 0):

`react-select` seems to be only accepting `value` and `label` as props (and possibly other HTML attributes that an `<option>` accepts), so I did this with the help of a function:

```
const options = [
   { value: "a", label: "A", tooltip: "yellow" },
   { value: "b", label: "B", tooltip: "orange" },
   { value: "c", label: "C", tooltip: "blue"   },
];

function getTooltip(value) {
   return options.find(x => x.value === value).tooltip;
}

/* A custom option component as an example */
const Option = (props) => {
   return (
      <components.Option {...props}>
         <div data-tip={getTooltip(props.value)}>
             {props.label}
         </div>
      </components.Option>
   );
};

/* Pass the custom component to <Select> */
return (
   <Select options={options} components={{ Option }} />
)
```